# Color map plotting, Error using surf() Data dimensions must agree

Tags: matlab, error-handling, colormap

I am trying to make a colour map plot using the following code:

```
[x,z] = meshgrid(0:100:600,0:100:600);
mm = size(z);
for z2 = 1:3
    for x2 = 1:3
        E(z2,x2) = (x(x2))^2 + (z(z2))^2;
    end  
end

figure;
surf(x,z,E,'EdgeColor','None');
view(2);
xlabel('x','fontsize',20);
ylabel('z','fontsize',20);
colormap jet;
```

I used z2 and x2 in the for loop because I only want to use the first to third element in the meshgrid, which means, 0,100,200 for both x and z, but matlab returns me the error:

Error using surf (line 74)
Data dimensions must agree.

Error in testgraph (line 10)
surf(x,z,E,'EdgeColor','None');

But if I set z2 = 3:7 and x2 = 3:7, then it can produce a graph without an error, but I don't know why is this, and how can I achieve what I want to plot?

Comment: surf requires the shape of all three to be the same. The shape of E happens to be the correct shape when you chose  z2 = 3:7 and x2 = 3:7,

Comment: If I understand correctly what you want you need to first initialize E. So before the loop starts add the line E = zeros(size(x)), then you should be able to do the 1:3 that you want in each loop

Answer (score 0):

Matrix dimensions are not matched. Since you made 7by7 meshgrid matrix, the result matrix E has to be 7by7 matrix.

Please, try below code.

```
[x,z] = meshgrid(0:100:600,0:100:600);
mm = size(z);

E=zeros(7,7); %initializing result matrix E

for z2 = 1:3
    for x2 = 1:3
        E(z2,x2) = (x(x2))^2 + (z(z2))^2;
    end  
end

figure;
surf(x,z,E,'EdgeColor','None');
view(2);
xlabel('x','fontsize',20);
ylabel('z','fontsize',20);
colormap jet;
```

In case of 3:7, since result matrix E is 7by7 matrix, you could avoid matrix dimension error.